# Could not instantiate persister org.hibernate.persister.entity.JoinedSubclassEntityPersister with OracleDB

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I am trying to map a existing Oracle DB to JPA Classes. But I am getting the mentioned error in the subject line. Not able to find out what is the real issue. Maybe I am mapping the entities wrong.

Have already tried changing the way classes are defined. Also tried the same on PostgreSQL where it works fine.

```
CREATE TABLE "JDTA_ITEM_MULTI_ATTRS" 
   (    "JDTA_ITEM_ID" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "ATTR_DATA_VALUE_ID" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "ATTR_DATA_TYPE_ID" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "JDTA_ITEM_MULTI_ATTRS_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("JDTA_ITEM_ID", "ATTR_DATA_VALUE_ID"))

CREATE TABLE "ATTR_DATA_KSATRS" 
   (    "ATTR_DATA_VALUE_ID" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "KSATR_TYPE_ID" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "ATTR_DATA_KSATRS_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ATTR_DATA_VALUE_ID"))

CREATE TABLE "DVMHR4W"."ATTR_DATA_RESOURCES" 
   (    "ATTR_DATA_VALUE_ID" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "ATTR_DATA_RESOURCE_TYPE_ID" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "PART_NUMBER" VARCHAR2(150 BYTE), 
    "SRC" VARCHAR2(300 BYTE), 
     CONSTRAINT "ATTR_DATA_RESOURCES_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ATTR_DATA_VALUE_ID"))
```

Below are the Java Entity Classes in short. Getter setters and Constructors have been removed to keep it short.

```java
@Entity
@IdClass(JdtaItemMultiAttrsPk.class)
@Table(name = "JDTA_ITEM_MULTI_ATTRS")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class JdtaItemMultiAttrs
        implements Serializable
{
    /**
     * generated id
     */
    private static final long  serialVersionUID = 8002L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "jdta_item_id")
    private int                jdtaItemId;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "attr_data_value_id")
    private int                attributeDataValueId;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "attr_data_value_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private AttributeDataValue attributeDataValue;

    @Column(name = "attr_data_type_id")
    private int                attributeDataTypeId;
}

public class JdtaItemMultiAttrsPk
        implements Serializable
{
    /**
     * generated id
     */
    private static final long  serialVersionUID = 8002L;

    private int                jdtaItemId;

    private int                attributeDataValueId;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "ATTR_DATA_RESOURCES")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumns({@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "attr_data_value_id")
, @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "jdta_item_id")})
public class AttrDataResource extends JdtaItemMultiAttrs
        implements Serializable
{
    /**
     * generated id
     */
    private static final long    serialVersionUID = 1600L;

    @Column(name = "attr_data_value_id",insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "attr_data_resource_type_id")
    private int                  attrDataResourceTypeId;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "attr_data_resource_type_id",insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private AttrDataResourceType attrDataResourceType;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "attr_data_value_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private AttributeDataValue attributeDataValue;

    @Column(name = "part_number")
    private String               partNumber;

    @Column(name = "src")
    private String               source;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "ATTR_DATA_KSATRS")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumns({@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "attr_data_value_id")
, @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "jdta_item_id")})
public class AttributeDataKsatr extends JdtaItemMultiAttrs
        implements Serializable
{
    /**
     * generated id
     */
    private static final long  serialVersionUID = 1L;


    @Column(name = "attr_data_value_id",insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private int id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ksatr_type_id")
    private KsatrType          type;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "attr_data_value_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private AttributeDataValue attributeDataValue;
}
```

Here is the error when I run this

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not instantiate persister org.hibernate.persister.entity.JoinedSubclassEntityPersister
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:402) ~[spring-orm-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377) ~[spring-orm-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1837) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1774) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not instantiate persister org.hibernate.persister.entity.JoinedSubclassEntityPersister
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:112) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:77) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.initialize(MetamodelImpl.java:154) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:295) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:467) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:939) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) ~[spring-orm-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) ~[spring-orm-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: null
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:854) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.JoinedSubclassEntityPersister.<init>(JoinedSubclassEntityPersister.java:301) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:96) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    ... 28 common frames omitted
```

Need to find what is exactly causing the issue here. I am using Spring Boot 2.1.5 and Hibernate 5.3.9/11, Oracle DB.

When I tried to replicate the same scenario in PostgreSQL it worked.

Comment: You can try to set a breakpoint on JoinedSubclassEntityPersister.java line 30 and then you will see what causes the error.

Comment: Did That. The Entity AttributeDataKsatr is expecting 2 primary key columns and finds only 1 column there. But I am not able to understand what causes it. Because I have specified 2 Primary Key Joins

Comment: I tried the same thing with PostgreSQL. Even Debugged it. Compared both. When its PostgreSQL it returns 2 primary key columns correctly. But when its Oracle it only returns 1

Comment: Are you generating the tables or are they already there?

Comment: They are already there. Its a existing DB.

Comment: I think you can remove PrimaryKeyJoinColumns because there is nothing diffrent from the base class

Comment: Yes you were right. They donot make any difference. But the error remains.

Comment: Can you provide a simple example of your problem on GitHub so I can reproduce the error?

Comment: I am trying to reproduce the same. But not able to :(

Comment: Hi @SimonMartinelli - Here is the code to reproduce the issue. https://github.com/mithilwane/MappingIssue